# Dropping an object from really high, landing at 0 velocity due to 'free' reverse thrust

Tags: aerodynamics

So a friend had an 'idea' where you could make an object land with 0 velocity.

Basically the idea is that you drop an object (like a rocket shape) from some altitude. To the object you attach fins (fixed propeller blades so to speak.) as it falls it starts rotating, due to the attached fins.

Now at some altitude above the ground you either:

1) You rotate the fins to get reverse 'thrust' (you don't really have thrust, but you would slow down rotation.) 
2) Retract the fins and expand new ones that face the opposite way (so they counter spin)
3) something along those lines (like extending flaps)

Now one of the arguments he had as to why this works is because you could expand larger fins for the counter rotation, therefore getting more drag and generating more 'lift'.

It feels like you cannot do this, but I cannot give a (good enough) reasonable explanation as to why it would or would not work (I'm a noob in this area.) So let's ask the people in the know... that's you.

I would love to see some 'proof' more so than speculation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I should have added that the system cannot have any energy added to it, so the mechanism of expanding the fins, or whatever other mechanism, should come from the energy gained from the rotation.

Comment: This question is simply about energy management in a < 100% efficient closed system and not aviation and therefore belongs on Physics.SE.

Comment: I vote to migrate this to physics.se

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Physics.SE

Comment: Come to think of it... Ever seen a maple seed?

Comment: Now if only I found a migrate button

Answer (score 8):

What you are describing is similar to a helicopter [autorotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorotation).  That is something that does work.  The rotors both generate drag and store rotational momentum.  Then, some of the momentum is converted to lift for landing.

Comment: Or an autogyro/gyrocopter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autogyro

Comment: Autorotation requires forward speed; the question refers to dropping the object.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, sustained autorotation does require forward speed, but the final flare does not.

Comment: @JanHudec I think you may have that the wrong way around.  I can autorotate all the way down with zero, or even negative forward speed, but I do need some to flare?

Comment: @Simon, by "flare" I mean when you pull on the collective at the end to arrest the descent. That shouldn't need forward speed, does it?

Comment: @JanHudec The "flare" is pulling back on the cyclic to convert kinetic energy (speed) into rotor RPM so that you can next use collective to increase pitch.  If you do not flare at the bottom, you will hit the ground hard since there is not enough energy stored in the rotors to arrest the rate of descent.  Without forward speed for the flare, you will crash in an autorotation from above hover height.

Comment: @Simon, I see. The device in question could have a flywheel to have more energy in the rotation and thus do without this part though.

Comment: @JanHudec Nope.  The flywheel cannot be 100% efficient so will also lose energy, meaning that it will take more energy than it can give back.

Comment: @Simon, nobody needs the same amount of energy back. At the final position, the device will have much less (by $mg\delta h$) energy than it had at the point of release. What it needs to do is dissipate that energy in a controlled way. A controlled way that is very similar to what autorotating helicopter does.

Answer (score 1):

Given the object has a terminal velocity, it should be possible.

Before it hits the ground, it has a speed no greater than terminal speed.  Assuming it has some sufficient propeller system, it will require a finite amount of energy to slow the descent to zero at the altitude desired.  But since the start point is arbitrarily high, we can collect an arbitrarily large amount of energy from the fall.

Imagine a quadcopter with depleted batteries and some sort of charging system that can be driven from the rotors.  Drop it from a height and let the descent charge up the battery.  Then a few feet before the ground, turn on the motors and let it hover.

Now this example uses batteries and electronics, but the argument doesn't change in character if you turn it into a kinetic spinning rotor instead (it's just harder to build).

Comment: It cannot be zero terminal velocity because it means a 100% efficience in loading the free fall nergy and 100% efficience in transforming that energy in lift

Comment: This will not work.  You must think in terms of systems and the total energy in them.  Without adding energy from outside the system, the energy in the system will always reduce.  Charging the batteries takes energy from whatever is producing lift at less than 100% efficiency.  The lift generators themselves lose energy through drag, friction etc.  With a system such as yours, the total energy decreases rapidly and will be very much less than when you started (with nothing but potential energy) and you cannot "cushion" your landing.

Comment: @Simon, why is 100% efficiency required here?  It's not.  The drag during the fall means the kinetic energy that has to be corrected near the ground is only a fraction of the potential energy available at the beginning of the fall.  If I can extract just that fraction, I have sufficient energy to stop at the bottom.

Comment: @jean, Nothing in the answer should suggest that it has zero terminal velocity or 100% efficiency.  Neither are required.  It simply has to have some drag (and therefore a positive terminal velocity).

Comment: A small positive terminal velocity is ok but also note drag is "stealing" energy from the fall and it's energy you cannot store. Drag itself is not 100% efficient meaning just a fraction of the energy its subtracting from the fall is actualy used to slow dows the velocity.

Comment: @jean, correct, but entirely sufficient in this problem.  If we wanted to end the exercise at the original altitude, the lack of 100% efficiency would prevent us.  But since we want to end the exercise on the ground, we can throw away tremendous amounts of energy to drag and still succeed.

Comment: Yeah but that's a answer for how a parachute works not for OP question =)

Comment: @BowlOfRed It is a closed system.  What will you convert the kinetic energy into to come to a safe stop?  You cannot gain any energy, and you cannot store it 100% efficiently.  Therefore, you will have less stored energy available to stop the descent than has been converted from potential energy into kinetic energy.  There is one simple rule, you don't get anything for nothing in a closed energy system.

Comment: The same thing that a running quadcopter converts the energy in its battery to: air motion and eventually heat.

Comment: How is charging the quadcopter batteries different (in principle, of course) from a "porpoising" descent in a sailplane?  You start level at say 10K ft, dive to 9K, climb back to 9800 ft (going through a nice 0g at the top of your climb), and so on, converting potential energy to kinetic and back again, with of course some loss at each step.  With the quadcopter, you convert some of the potential energy of height to electrochemical energy in the battery, then recover it.

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of the defunct Roton experimental rocket, except that it had helicopter rotor blades powered by rockets at the tip to take off.

It could be achieved with just one set of blades that have a very large pitch range adjustment. Pitch the blades downwards on descent so that they'll spin like a windmill and let the angular momentum build up, then pitch the blades upwards to convert the angular momentum into lift. The rotor system would require a flywheel of some sort to store the momentum needed to slow the craft down by a decent amount.

Comment: As it is this post should be a comment, not an answer. However the content is very interesting, so you should try to make it a full answer before it is closed as "not an answer". Welcome to the site, I hope to read many good questions and answers from you.

Comment: My apologies for posting a question that was 'off-topic'. In any case I want to thank all the people who replied. While going through the answers I read up some more about some terms people used, which led down to a late night reading many interesting things. So I learned a couple new things, which is always fun. Thanks again for all the replies.